# Show GitHub Commits on Website

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, web, github

I saw a neat idea on a website that I would like to replicate.  On the site (link provided below), it appears as though they are just loading in the commits from their private repository and displaying them in a basic Bootstrap table.

https://avicus.net/revisions

Do you know how I can proceed to attain such results ? Is there a public resource I can access so that I can accomplish a similar result ?

The link provided is the one I preferred among several I have seen around. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are most likely using the Github API to pull the necessary data, probably with an ajax request or something similar. I suggest you go through [the Github API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/) to understand how to retrieve data from a repository.

Keep in mind that similar APIs usually allow you to retrieve the necessary data in JSON format which you then need to parse. Once that is done you can display it however you like using html + css + js or jQuery.